# Unable to execute select statement after defining an analyzer in a do loop

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to execute an SQL file in Postgres. I am fairly new to this but have experience in other SQL languages. The objective is to run this .sql file and it returns a table count. Context is huge in this problem which I don't think is needed since the issue is of syntax.

I tried reading the official documentation to find something around analyzers and do loops but in vain.

This is the sql file:

```
-- PostgreSQL schema analyze and report table counts

do language plpgsql
$ANALYZER$
DECLARE
   anly RECORD;
BEGIN
   for anly in
   (select 'analyze ' || relname as synt
   FROM pg_class join pg_namespace on (pg_class.relnamespace = pg_namespace.oid)
   WHERE nspname = 'public' and relkind = 'r'
   )
   LOOP
   EXECUTE anly.synt;
END
LOOP;
end;
$ANALYZER$


SELECT relname, reltuples
FROM pg_class join pg_namespace on (pg_class.relnamespace = pg_namespace.oid)
WHERE nspname = 'public' and relkind = 'r'
ORDER BY relname;
```

When I run the file using the command:

```
psql -d assignment_4 -f 06-analyze_and_count.sql
```

I get the following error:

```
2019-11-05 16:45:29.015 EST [17108] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT" at character 323
2019-11-05 16:45:29.015 EST [17108] STATEMENT:  do language plpgsql $ANALYZER$
    DECLARE
       anly RECORD;
    BEGIN
       for anly in (select 'analyze ' || relname as synt
       FROM pg_class join pg_namespace on (pg_class.relnamespace = pg_namespace.oid)
                        WHERE nspname = 'public' and relkind = 'r'
       ) LOOP
          EXECUTE anly.synt;
       END LOOP;
    end;
    $ANALYZER$
    SELECT relname, reltuples
                        FROM pg_class join pg_namespace on (pg_class.relnamespace = pg_namespace.oid)
                        WHERE nspname = 'public' and relkind = 'r'
    ORDER BY relname;
psql:06-analyze_and_count.sql:24: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 13: SELECT relname, reltuples
         ^
```

I am unable to deduce what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected the `end;$ANALYZER$` to `end $ANALYZER$;` and it worked. 
Reference: "PL/pgSQL block structure example" described [here](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-block-structure/).